# If $S_1=0$ and $S_2=0$ represent two non intersecting circles, what does $S_1+\lambda S_2=0$ represent?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

> If $S_1=0$ and $S_2=0$ represent two non intersecting circles, what does $S_1+\lambda S_2=0$ represent?

I know that $S_1+\lambda S_2=0$ represent the family of circles that are [coaxial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_circles#Radical_axis_and_central_line) with $S_1=0$ and $S_2=0$, (where $\lambda\ne -1$, because then it would become the radical axis) but I cannot see it geometrically. If the circles are intersecting, then it is clear that $S_1+\lambda S_2=0$ represents the family of circles passing through their common points of intersection and hence they would have the same [radical axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_axis), that is, their common chord. How do I prove that for non intersecting circles?

Secondly, I want to ask if we are given a line $L=0$ and a circle $S=0$, what does $S+\lambda L=0$ represent if they are non intersecting? For intersecting case, it is clearly that it would be family of circles passing through their points of intersection. I think it would represent the circles $S'=0$ such that $S=0$ and $S'=0$ have the radical axis $L=0$, but there is no intuition, because intersection points are imaginary.

Maybe it is just that everything is right in front of me, but I am not able to understand it clearly. I would prefer a complete answer rather than comments.

Comment: Have you sketched what happens in an example such as the circles $(x\pm 2)^2+y^2=1$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician: Can you please elaborate? The circles you describe will have the radical axis as the $y$ axis.

Comment: Well if you're trying to get some intuition you also need to sketch the other circles of the family.

Comment: @ancientmathematician: If you are talking about the diagrams shown [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoaxalCircles.html), then yes, I have seen this. But still my question remains...

Comment: I think regardless of whether the circles are intersecting, this could be proven just by taking $S_1$ as $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$ and $S_2$ as $(x-h')^2+(y-k')^2=r'^2$ and just doing the calculation as you would with @ancientmathematician's example.

Comment: And to make it simpler, you could envision scaling the circles and repositioning so you could take $S_1$ to be exactly $x^2+y^2=1$, the circle of radius 1 centered at the origin.

Comment: @ndhanson3 that is definitely a way to go, in which we find the radical axis of the two circles by subtracting and then taking $S_1+\lambda S_2=0$ and find it's radical axis with any of the circles, and showing them to be the same line. However, I seek an easier/intuitive approach as to why $S_1+\lambda S_2=0$ gives the family of coaxial circles. Because this is clearly possible in intersecting circles, so in this case also there should be an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Your two questions are in fact one, because the pencil for circles $C_1+\lambda C_2$ contains the radical axis of $C_1,C_2$ (the one that you rejected), and conversely, the pencil $C+\lambda L$ defined by a circle and a line is such that $L$ is the radical axis of $C and another circle in the pencil.

WLOG, consider

$$\begin{cases}S_1\equiv x^2+y^2=1,\\S_2\equiv(x-d)^2+y^2=r^2.\end{cases}$$ By subtraction, the line in the pencil is

$$L\equiv d(2x-d)=1-r^2$$ or

$$x=\frac d2+\frac{1-r^2}{2d}.$$

The distances of the intersection with the axis $x$ to the centers are

$$\pm\frac d2+\frac{1-r^2}{2d}$$ and we do have by Pythagoras

$$\left(\frac d2+\frac{1-r^2}{2d}\right)^2-1^2=\left(-\frac{d}2+\frac{1-r^2}{2d}\right)^2-r^2,$$

which proves that the lengths of the tangent segments to the circles from this point have equal lengths and the line is the radical axis.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_axis#/media/File:Radical_axis_orthogonal_circles.svg

These families of circles are well illustrated by the Appolonius' coordinates system:

[image]

Comment: I was already convinced that subtracting two equations of circles gives the radical axis. However, I have thought of an answer for my own question, instead of writing $S_1+\lambda S_2=0$, if we take $k S_1+(1-k)S_2=0$, and suppose we take $S_1=0$, then by subtracting the two equations, we get $(k-1)(S_1-S_2)=0$ which is their radical axis! (provided $k\ne 1$, because we are talking of two different circles).